# Fill edges and center of array/vector with different values

Tags: c++, c++17

I would like to create a function which initializes a vector or array of size `width * height`, but which also creates a border around these values.

The values around the outside also need to be initialized to a different value from the ones in the center.

The objects I am storing do not have a default constructor, so I cannot rely on that for initialization.

This is the code I have so far, but it feels like there should be a simpler or more idiomatic way of doing this.

I can use any features up to and including C++1z.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void fill_values(const unsigned width, const unsigned height, std::vector<int> &values) {
    for(unsigned y=0; y<height+2; ++y) {
        for(unsigned x=0; x<width+2; ++x) {
            if(x==0 || x==width+1 || y==0 || y==height+1) {
                values.push_back(1);
            } else {
                values.push_back(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const unsigned width = 4;
    const unsigned height = 3;
    std::vector<int> values;

    fill_values(width, height, values);

    for(unsigned y=0; y<height+2; ++y) {
        for(unsigned x=0; x<width+2; ++x) {
            std::cout << values[y * (width+2) + x];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output : -

```
111111
100001
100001
100001
111111
```

Comment: why do you use a single vector to represent a matrix?
with a vector of vector it could be simpler.

Comment: @Federico All rows are the same size and the vector is wrapped in a class. It seemed simpler to have a `get(unsigned x, unsigned y) { return values[y*width + x]; }` than to initialize a vector-of-vectors. I also imagine that a one-dimensional vector would be faster to access as only one indirection is taking place, would that be correct?

Comment: I don't think the code will be so faster to justify a less clear implementation.
When i see this: `values[y*width + x]`; if i don't know that `values` is a matrix, it took me a while to realize that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, your code is fine. I pretty easily understood what it does.

But in the spirit of proposing alternate complex implementations, I'd propose the following. A different way to fill the matrix is to add a full row of 1s, then `height` rows of `1000...001`, then another full row of 1s. We can make that a bit more explicit. Also, would suggest returning a `vector` instead of filling it:

```
std::vector<int> fill_values(const unsigned width, const unsigned height) {
    std::vector<int> m;
    m.reserve((width + 2) * (height + 2));

    // add row of 1s
    m.insert(m.end(), width + 2, 1);

    // add height middle rows
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        m.push_back(1);
        m.insert(m.end(), width, 0);
        m.push_back(1);
    }

    // and a final row of 1s
    m.insert(m.end(), width + 2, 1);

    return m;
}
```

Comment: Seems like the closest to what I was looking for, though more difficult to mentally parse :)

Answer (score 2):

As @Fedorico said in the comments, using a vector of vectors is a better representation for your values variable.  Rather than pass the values by reference as a parameter, it would be better to depend on [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) for the return value.  I also found it easier to just use the set height and width to be the total number of rows and cols in the data so that there's no need to add two.

The following code depends on c++11 or newer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Fills the 2D matrix with 1s on the border and 0s in the middle.
vector<vector<int>> generate_matrix(int rows, int cols);
void print_matrix(const vector<vector<int>>& matrix);

int main()
{
    // Don't sync I/O with C stdio.
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    // Height and Width of the entire 2D matrix.
    const int rows = 6;
    const int cols = 5;

    vector<vector<int>> matrix = generate_matrix(rows, cols);
    print_matrix(matrix);

    return 0;
}

vector<vector<int>> generate_matrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    // fill a rows x cols 2D vector with 0s.
    vector<vector<int>> matrix(rows, vector<int>(cols, 0));

    // fill in 1s on top and bottom rows.
    if (rows > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
        {
            matrix[0][i] = 1;
            matrix[rows-1][i] = 1;
        }
    }

    // fill in 1s on the left and right columns.
    if (cols > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        {
            matrix[i][0] = 1;
            matrix[i][cols-1] = 1;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

void print_matrix(const vector<vector<int>>& matrix)
{
    // Use a reference for the row iterator to prevent a vector copy.
    for (auto& row : matrix)
    {
        for (auto element : row)
        {
            cout << element;
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also use the `fill` method of vectors to set the first and last row with 1.
But, anyway, i still prefer this solution with a real matrix instead of a single vector.

Answer (score 1):

Not a great difference, but you can use `std::generate_n()` (starting from c++11) with a lambda function.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
 {
    constexpr std::size_t  width  { 4U };
    constexpr std::size_t  height { 3U };
    constexpr std::size_t  w2     { width + 2U };
    constexpr std::size_t  h2     { height + 2U };

    std::vector<int> values;

    values.resize ( w2 * h2 );

    std::generate_n(values.begin(), w2 * h2, [=]() -> int
     { 
       static std::size_t i = -1;

       ++i;

       return     ( 0U == i / w2 ) || ( h2 - 1U == i / w2 ) 
               || ( 0U == i % w2 ) || ( w2 - 1U == i % w2 );
     });

    for(unsigned y=0; y<height+2; ++y) {
        for(unsigned x=0; x<width+2; ++x) {
            std::cout << values[y * (width+2) + x] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If `width` and `heigth` are known at compile time, you can initialize the `std::vector` (or the `std::array`?) with initializer list, using a little template work (give me some time and I'll show an example).

Comment: Unfortunately width and height are not known at compile time. After being initialized, the matrix is used until it is eventually re-initialized with another width and height.

Comment: @Caw - what a pity.